# How to set parent div height to self adapt to the inner div height?

Tags: css, html

I have a parent div and 2 sub div as follow:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div style="height:100px; float:left;" >
        aaa
    </div>
    <div style="height:200px; float:left;">
        bbb
    </div>
</div>​
```

How to set the "parent" css to adapt to the largest height of inner div? In this case: 200px

PS: Neither `height=100%` nor `height=auto` works.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also "overflow:hidden" on the parent element, although you may encounter problems if you want things to break out of that div (e.g. negative margins, box-shadow, etc).

```
<div class="parent" style="overflow: hidden;">
    <div style="height:100px; float:left;" >
        aaa
    </div>
    <div style="height:200px; float:left;">
        bbb
    </div>
</div>​
```

Comment: Should have said... that means that you don't need the "clear" div.

Comment: I don't think this has any influence on parent's height, does it? 
Try adding `<style>div {border:1px dotted red;}</style>` - parent still seems to be 0px in height....

Answer (score 3):

The parent div does not take the height of its content, because the inner divs are floating. You have to clear the floating, before closing the parent div. Try this:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div style="height:100px; float:left;" >
        aaa
    </div> 
    <div style="height:200px; float:left;">
        bbb
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>​
```

---

**EDIT**: You might want to have a look at this w3c article for in-depth information about floats and clearing: http://www.w3.org/wiki/Floats_and_clearing

Answer (score 1):

I followed the link given by [peterp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1006823/peterp) and would like to quote a method they mention, which worked for me. This method is first on their list and described as *simply* :)

**Make the outer `div` also `float`**

```
<div class="parent" style="float:left;">
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add style="clear:both"

```
<div class="parent">
       <div style="height:100px; float:left;" >
           asljkdh        
       </div> 
       <div style="height:200px; float:left;">
          bbb 
       </div>
       <div style="clear:both"></div> <!-- Add this Line-->
     </div>​
```